# Kitchen floor is sloping

Tags: basement, flooring, foundation

I am a first time home owner, hoping maybe people can give some advice. I have a 120+ year old home.

I noticed a slope in my kitchen floor. I got an inspection done (from a generalist not a structural engineer), they stated that they did not find anything that would indicate a foundation issue, and that it's likely just settling. However, since the basement seemed to have ended before reaching the kitchen (there was a closet in the basement that seemed to lead to the area underneath the kitchen. But that closet had some woodwork done, covering the walls with plywood and installing a wooden DIY shelf), they could not know for certain, as the shelves and plywood obstructed the view of the walls. We weren't certain if the walls went back further or not.

I have since, demolished the closet: plywood and shelf, only to find a brick wall. So it seems like there really aren't any beams underneath the kitchen. Unlike the rest of the basement/house.

I am thinking maybe when the previous owner installed the new floors, maybe they installed something incorrectly. Or maybe it the subfloor in that section is weak.

Any advice?

I've attached a picture, note the yellow line on the floor and the bottom of the kitchen cabinet. The slope seems extreme. Something to note also, the sloping really only starts after the stove. As denoted by the yellow line.

[image]

Comment: A picture of the basement ceiling and wall will be more helpful, so we can see what is holding the kitchen floor up.  We can't tell what is causing the slope from above.  If there is a finished ceiling in the basement will make it harder to see the supports.

Comment: @crip659 to be clear, after demolishing the woodwork in the closet, in the basement. It became clear that the actual basement does not go underneath the kitchen.

Comment: I see out-of-parallel between the cabinet and a chunk of wood in the toe kick area. The chunk of wood's out of parallel with the cabinet obscures the "slope," where I think you meant sag. You probably have a "creep" problem from some combination of aging and undersized floor joists. If it's crawlspace under there, then a midspan header below is probably your easiest fix.

Comment: Do you have a crawl space under this area?  What does the area under the kitchen look like from outside?  Where would this brick wall stop in respect to your kitchen photo - is it parallel to the outside wall with the face of your dishwasher?  Are your joists running parallel with the stove face such that they cantilever on top of the brick wall and extend outside picking up the floor load?  is this section of the kitchen a cantilever - outside pic of kitchen wall will help.

Comment: @FreshCodemonger to be clear, the brick wall I found in my basement, as far as I can tell, stops right at the entrance to the kitchen, which is to BEFORE the right side of the stove. I haven't seen a crawlspace for the area underneath the kitchen.

Comment: sure so are your floor joists parallel or perpendicular to the brick wall ?

Comment: What is under the kitchen? Are there posts under beams with joists framing into the beams. Take a few pictures of the area under the kitchen. Ground interface to any foundation. Foundation interface to beams. Beams interface to joists.

Comment: @FreshCodemonger the basement, which covers the main section of my house, and not the kitchen, the floor joists in that area are parallel to the brick. Meaning they do not "intersect", instead they run along side by side with the brick wall

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.